# How to manipulate loops with input?

Tags: javascript, html-select

i got a for loop and `i` would like to manipulate the counter `i` with a input on screen. Below i can select from 1 to 10 and i want this selection to get replaced by the counter in the loop. That means when i choose 2, then `i` should be 2. I started with the code below, but `document.getElementById('options').innerHTML = "i"`; seems to be the wrong code to manipulate. Thanks so much for your help!

```
        <select id="options" size="1">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
         </select>

    for (i=0, i<someArray; i++){
    do somethingWith[i];}

document.getElementById('options').innerHTML = "i";
```

Comment: When does the loop execute? What is "do something"?

Comment: you want `someArray` to be the *selected* value?

Comment: This part is not important. Just some random loop.

Comment: yes, i want someArray to be the selected array

Comment: you need to get the `value` of the `select` element: `document.querySelector('#options').value`

Comment: I hope you aware `document.getElementById('options').innerHTML` will remove all `<option>` tag and replace everything with `"i"`

Comment: @Suppe It's very important *when* this random loop runs. If it runs before the user selection is made, it will always use the default value. Do you want to run it every time the user makes a selection?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value of the `select` element and assign that to `i`.

```
var i = document.querySelector('#options').value;

for(i < someArray; i++){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to HTML

```
<select onChange="doWork(this)">
```

In Js

```
function doWork(obj){

         obj.innerHTML = obj.value

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to do some thing on selection, use onchange method with select to trigger a function every time you are selecting an option.

```
 <select id="options" size="1" onchange="myFunction()">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
         </select>


<p id="demo"></p>



<script>
function myFunction() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("options").value;
    var somethingWith = [];
    for (i=0; i < selectedValue; i++){
        somethingWith.push(i);
    }

    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = somethingWith;
}
</script>
```

**But if you only want to dynamically select an option in select tag, this might help**

```
Select your favorite fruit:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">banana</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "banana";
}
</script>
```